# Get all pixel data from Bitmap object

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want to fill up a `double[400]` array with pixel data as seen in the below code.

I have been searching for the answer and I still haven't found one. My attempt is:

```
Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(fileName);
numberVisual.Image = bm;
long overallIteration = 0;

for (long i = 0; i <= 20/*bm.Width*/; ++i)
{
    for (long h = 0; h <= 20/*bm.Height*/; ++h)
    {
        input[/*(i * h)*/overallIteration] =
            bm.GetPixel((int)h, (int)i) != Color.White ? 0 : 1;
        ++overallIteration;
    }
}
```

It gives off an exception on

> bm.GetPixel System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Parameter must be
>   positive and < Width.

All the bitmaps I am using are 20x20px.

Comment: change <=  to < ! (c# is zero-based!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the height and the width of the image you are loading, if your image is 20x20, you have to iterate from 0 to 19 and not from 0 to 20

**Right code**

```
    for (long i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        for (long h = 0; h < 20; ++h)
        {
```

**Wrong code**

```
    for (long i = 0; I <= 20; ++i)
    {
        for (long h = 0; h <= 20; ++h)
        {
```